# Button is not relocating to center of image when I resize browser

Tags: performance, button, repair

I've been trying to fix this for a while. I have an image right under my navigation bar and I placed a button right in the middle of that image. The problem is that whenever I resize the browser the button stays in the same place and doesn't move with the image to the center of it. 
Please help
Thanks!
[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQjbF.png)
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxr1C.png)

Comment: Please include (copy/paste) the text of your CSS & HTML in the question instead of the links to the imgur images.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using `position: absolute;`. For this you'd want to add the following rule to the container of the button.

```css
.ScheduleAppointmentWrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Don't add the lines 7 & 8 */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ScheduleAppointmentWrapper">
  <button id="ScheduleAppointment">SCHEDULE APPOINTMENT</button>
</div>
```

If there is another element within the parent component, you can add the following styles:

```css
.ScheduleAppointmentWrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

img.button-image {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#ScheduleAppointment {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ScheduleAppointmentWrapper">
  <img class="button-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/djx0P7/11.jpg" alt="Flower">
  <button id="ScheduleAppointment">SCHEDULE APPOINTMENT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It positioned it in the middle but not on the image I have on there, it was put below it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you in last comment.

Comment: You should have shown the full markup around the button so that I could get the full context of the layout.

Comment: For a responsive design, I would suggest that you use the background-image property instead of a separate image.